# Loop through the dates in a column in qlik sense

Tags: qliksense

I am trying to loop through all the possible pairs of date combinations in a date column and find out the pairs of date combinations which are less than or equal to 8 days apart.
I have tried implementing the following in the script, but it didn't work.
Any guidance would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
// Create a mapping table to store all possible date combinations
DateCombinations:
LOAD
    Date AS Date1,
    Date AS Date2
RESIDENT DataTable;

// Join the mapping table with itself to calculate the days between all pairs of dates
JOIN (DateCombinations)
LOAD
    Date1,
    Date2,
    Date1 - Date2 AS DaysBetween
RESIDENT DateCombinations
WHERE Date1 <> Date2;

// Drop the temporary mapping table
DROP TABLE DateCombinations;
```

Comment: Example input, and desired output would be nice to have! (Please, use [edit to add that info to the question), and I do not see any reference to `8 days apart` in your code.....